# SOAP::Lite generates "overflow" on complex type "Array"

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl, asmx

I use SOAP::Lite to communicate to a "SOAP"-Service-WSDL (ASMX resp).
This Service requires an array of arguments, like so:

```
<scriptParameters>
  <string>string</string>
  <string2>string2</string2>
</scriptParameters>
```

In Perl I use the following code:

```
my @args;
my @params;
foreach (keys %{$self->{args}}) {
    push(@params, SOAP::Data->name($_ => $self->{args}->{$_})->type(""));
}
push(@data, SOAP::Data->name("scriptParameters" => SOAP::Data->value(\@params)->type(""))->type(""));
```

But this creates the following XML:

```
<scriptParameters soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[11]" xsi:type="namesp20">
  <job_id xsi:type="xsd:int">18381</job_id>
  <dump xsi:type="xsd:int">0</dump>
</scriptParameters
```

Note the *soapenc:arrayType...*-stuff in the scriptParameters-Element.

The problem now is, that the ASMX-Service does not recognize the scriptParameters array (I think because of the soapenc-stuff (unfortunately this is not debug'able). Does anyone has an idea how I can get rid of the additional data?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the actual service and not being able to experiment with various options this is a bit difficult. But in my experience the use of "soapenc:arrayType" is symptomatic of SOAP::Lite thinking that the service is an RPC/encoded SOAP service rather than document/literal or RPC/literal. So check which method you are using to create the service proxy, the '$soap->service($WSDL)' method assumes RPC/encoded, but '$soap->proxy()' method allows more control, at the cost of some additional complexity.

Persuading SOAP::Lite to produce the right XML can be a bit tricky. Have a look at the following sites for some hints on how to construct specific data structures using SOAP::Lite:

- [Complex SOAP::Lite requests - my rules for SOAP::Sanity!](http://tardate.blogspot.com/2007/02/complex-soaplite-requests-my-rules-for.html)
- http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/webservices/tutorials/06_programming/perl

From the later the sample code for the EB-eye web service (ebeye_soaplite.pl) is likely to be the most helpful since it uses lists/arrays a lot.

Depending on how tied to SOAP::Lite you are, you might want to have a look at the alternatives. I've found XML::Compile::SOAP to be quite a bit easier to use with document/literal SOAP services which use complex types.